# Postgresql and SSL certificat

Tags: postgresql, ssl, datadirectory

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL with another data directory.

The problem comes when I try to start postgresql I have the following error :

```
Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server: main[....] The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: 2014-04-16 22:14:51 CEST FATAL: could not load server [FAILficate file "server.crt": No such file or directory ... failed!
 failed!
```

I've tried a lot of things coming from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/418625/postgresql-root-crt-not-loading) or [here](http://forums.postgresql.fr/viewtopic.php?id=551) but nothing works for me.

My configuration file is in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/` but I don't know why I have a some other configuration files on my new data directory. (visibly they are not used).

Naturally I can fix this bug by commenting the `ssl = true` on the postgresql.conf but it's not at all the aim.

Comment: What do the relevant lines in your PostgreSQL config look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ssl-tcp.html) you should check your `$PGDATA` directory for the `server.crt` file. In cases is missing you should either request a new certificate or make self signed one and place the file there.

Comment: My mistake. You're completely right. Just apply [this](http://forums.postgresql.fr/viewtopic.php?id=551) to generate a new SSL key and do it (or move it) to $PGDATA. Thank you for your help !